# How can I delay an input submit button a few seconds?

Tags: html, forms

I have a form with two submit buttons.  The submit buttons are yes or no, requiring the user to answer a question that appears.  How can I program the submit buttons to pop up after a few second, to ensure they dont click them by accident (it happens).

Comment: some sort of scripting language in the browser. Javascript perhaps.

Comment: Write JavaScript that disables the buttons on page load and then enables them 5 seconds later.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you.

```
$('#yourForm').function() {
    var mapped = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
        mapped.submit();
    }, 5000); // will trigger after 5 seconds!
});
```

Comment: I tried wrapping that in a <script type="text/javascript"> tag, adding id="yesno" to my <form> tag and change yourForm to yesno.  No luck :/   <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#yesno').function() {
    var mapped = $(this);

    setTimeout(function() {
        mapped.submit();
    }, 5000); // will trigger after 5 seconds!
});
        </script>

Comment: that's not the correct usage of jQuery. you use jQuery mostly when document.readyState == "complete" and when other browser-related things are completed under jQuery Core... use this example: http://urloment.com/xWKAgwqfyv - means that you MUST use $.ready(function(){});

Comment: They're still loading when the page loads :/

Comment: Sorry, I just realized they are not submit buttons although they act the same.   They are  <input type="image".. />

Comment: use CSS to style your "input type="submit"" buttons and leave the type="image" behind.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with that code.  It does not work.

Comment: About my code not working? My proof is that when I load the page the images load right away...